# Aligning controls next to each other in relative layout

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I have 2 image buttons and 2 textviews I want to position them in this order

textview1 - imagebutton1 - textview2 - imagebutton2

Can anyone here help me with this?

here is what I tried but it is not working properly

```
<TextView
       android:id="@+id/like_count"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/comments_list"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" 
        android:text="10" />

      <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/like_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/comments_list"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/like_count"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/xml_like_button_selctor" />

      <TextView
       android:id="@+id/comment_count"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/like_button"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="10"/> 

     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/comment_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/comment_count"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/xml_comment_button_selector" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this..

You can use `LinearLayout` `android:orientation="horizontal"` and all child views `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/like_count"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="10"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/like_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/xml_like_button_selctor" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment_count"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="10"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/comment_icon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/xml_comment_button_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is there any way to programmatically position this whole linearlayout to say middle of the screen?

Comment: @Badrul set gravity center for layout.

Comment: thanks @hariharan just last query, how can I place all these controls close to each other. the way you suggested they have considerable space between each other. I want them tightly coupled

Comment: @Badrul If you do like that it'll give issue. If text is too long then `ImageButton`  will disappear. So that i given like that.

Comment: text in text view can't be more than XXXX(4 digits). Can you help now? they all should be tightly coupled and left aligned

Comment: @Badrul hmm k then you can use it . Remove `android:layout_weight="1"` and change `android:layout_width="0dp"` to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: Even though this answer is correct, it does not directly answer the question as the question needs to be answered for RelativeLayout. That is why @Prateek's answer is more suitable to be marked as the answer. (`android:layout_toRightOf` was the only necessary thing to share.)

Answer (score 10):

Please use the following Relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#EAEAEA" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text1"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        />

    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgButton1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text1"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text2"
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgButton1"
        />

    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text2"
        android:id="@+id/imgButton2"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a LinerLayout for this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_pane_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: there are many other controls I have on layout that is why I am using relative layout

Answer (score -1):

Change TextView width to `wrap_content`